# Upgrading from SQL Server 2008 Express to 2008 Developer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

What is the best (or THE) way to change my SQL Express 2008 (with advance...) installation to a 2008 Developer edition?

I need to keep the databases, along with the logins and so on.

I need to upgrade because, I Want to use all the features in TFS 2010.

- Do I have to make backups of all the data and uninstall express - install developer?
- Is there a quicker way?

**SOLVED:**

In the SQL Server Installation Center, there a Edition Upgrade options found under Maintenance. The only thing is that you have to choose processor type as x86 (as Express is only x86) in the options in the Installation Center. Now my SQL Server is developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had to do the same thing at one time. I think we simply backed up our database(s) and the master and msdb databases as a precaution, to restore if we had to, which I don't think we did.